# Accessing NSIndexPath from method

Tags: objective-c, nsindexpath

I am trying to access the indexPath of my tableView from a method that doesn't declare NSIndexPath.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
        {

            NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

            DetailScheduleViewController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detail"];

            svc.title = [[news objectAtIndex:tempIndexPath.row]objectForKey:@"Series"];

            svc.newsArticle = [news objectAtIndex:tempIndexPath.row];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];

            [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Of course, the issue here is this:

```
        NSIndexPath *tempIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

The indexPathForRow is 0 and it will only return the first cell item. Thats not what I want. I want to be able to return the whole list in the indexPath. How can I do this?

- Let me know if you guys need more clarification. Thanks!

Comment: You only ever use the `row` of `tempIndexPath`, so why do you need an index path? And what do you mean `the whole list in the indexPath` ?

Comment: Where does `index` come from? Is that not the same as the row?

Comment: jaydee3 answered my question. Best way is to save the indexPath. :)

Comment: The cell object should not know anything about business logic (that includes cell handling behaviour..the handling belongs to the table view). This solution might technically work, but it's a wrong design.

Comment: "Best way is to save the indexPath".  No, no it's not.  I don't know what code you've downloaded, but I suggest you check out its documentation.  I imagine the `index` argument the method caller is sending is probably equivalent to `indexPath.row` from a normal `UITableViewController` method.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ask the tableView for the indexPath like this:

```
- (void)swipeableTableViewCell:(SWTableViewCell *)cell didTriggerRightUtilityButtonWithIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

Comment: Thank you jaydee3! Perfect solution. Have been looking for this quite a bit. :)

Comment: This isn't the easiest solution, and although it works, it's certainly bad practice.  See Earl Grey's comment on the question.